# How to use metrics using Steeltoe Actuator + opencensus + Prometheus

Tags: .net-core, microservices, prometheus, opencensus, steeltoe

We are implementing enterprise level application using micro-services architecture.To implement it, .net core and JAVA are being used and it is used pivotal steeltoe framework to implement micro-services features for .net and sprint boot for JAVA.Now we are production ready and need to capture metrics in production environment. We are planing to use actuator framework and Prometheus + graffana dashboards.
Metrics monitoring can be achieved by actuator framework very easily.
If we want to implement same functionality using steeltoe we have to use opencensus to export metrics to Prometheus . My question is - Is there example which is supported to .net core to export metrics from opencensus to Prometheus via steeltoe.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Prometheus endpoint is supported with Steeltoe.  Take a look at the documentation here: https://steeltoe.io/docs/management/prometheus

HTH,

Jason